# Não cadastra no banco de dados PHP MySQL

Tags: php

Boa noite, gostaria de uma ajuda no meu código. Estou tentando salvar 3 valores no meu banco de dados e não estou conseguindo. Já revisei tudo certinho, vi e revi o código e nao encontro o erro. Na hora de cadastrar ele da o erro no echo(Erro ao inserir dados no bando de dados!). Segue meu código:

cadastro.php

```
  Nome <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome da Planta"><br>
  tipo <input type="text" name="tipo" placeholder="tipo da planta"><br>
  thc  <input type="text" name="thc"  placeholder="thc"><br>
```

conexao.php

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bd_winfo", "root", ""); 

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bd_winfo");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Falha ao conectar-se com o banco de dados MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

inserir.php

```
session_start();
    include_once("conexao.php");


    //Verifica se o usuario clicou no botao, se clicou, acessa o if e cadastra...se não....
    $enviarCadastro=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'enviarCadastro', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if($enviarCadastro) {
        //Recebe dados do formulario
        $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $tipo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tipo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $thc = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'thc', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        //Inserindo no banco de dados

        $result = "INSERT INTO strains ('nome', 'tipo', 'thc') VALUES (:nome, :tipo, :thc)";
        $insere_s = $pdo->prepare($result);
        $insere_s->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
        $insere_s->bindParam(':tipo', $tipo);
        $insere_s->bindParam(':thc', $thc);

        if($insere_s->execute()){
            echo"Sucesso";
        }else{
            echo"Erro ao inserir dados no bando de dados!";
        }


    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Cadastro nao realizado";
        header("Location: cadastroPlantas.php");
    }
```

Comment: Pelo que percebi vc tá fechando a conexão no próprio include `mysqli_close($link);`.... quando chegar na execução da query a conexão já foi fechada.

Comment: Não sei é isso, talvez tenha nada a ver, pq eu não entendo muito de conexão usando PHP, mas achei estranho.

Comment: Normalmente não tem necessidade nem de chamar mysqli_close() porque vai ser fechada quando o script terminar.

Comment: só um comentario, a conexao com o banco de dados esta tudo ok, a parte de conexao.php

Comment: O problema é na linha 4 caractere 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o erro! estava dando erro pois o thc é int e cadastrava como string. O que eu fiz foi fazer a conversão de string para int e deu certo!

```
$thc = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'thc', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//converte string para INT
$thc_int = (int)$thc;

//variável $thc_int convertida
$insere_s->bindParam(':thc', $thc_int);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mude a linha:

```
$result = "INSERT INTO strains ('nome', 'tipo', 'thc') VALUES (:nome, :tipo, :thc)";
```

Para:

```
$result = "INSERT INTO strains (nome, tipo, thc) VALUES (:nome, :tipo, :thc)";
```

Além disso você está abrindo a conexão com o banco com o PDO e o mysqli, 2 conexões (e só está fazendo uso do PDO), recomendo escolher somente uma para seu projeto, fora o fato de a logo após verificar se foi possível conectar utilizando mysqli você fecha a conexão (não faz muito sentido, esse bloco de código pode ser exluido).

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bd_winfo");
if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Falha ao conectar-se com o banco de dados MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Também não deu certo! Fiz as mudanças no conexão.php e na linha do $result. Continua dando erro ao inserir no banco de dados.

Comment: Tem como posta o erro que acontece aqui?

Comment: O erro que retorna é o do else do inserir.php.
if($insere_s->execute()){
   echo"Sucesso";
  }else{
   echo"Erro ao inserir dados no bando de dados!";
  }